# Setting page numbers correctly

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I'm preparing a paper and I created a `title` page, an `abstract` page and an acknowledgments page. Those pages must not show page numbers. So I used

```
\setcounter{page}{-1}
```

for the title page and

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{-1}
```

for the other pages.

In this way the page numbers aren't shown. But is it right to set the `page` counter to `-1` for all pages where I don't want show the number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `\setcounter{page}{-1}` in the middle of the document is likely to cause incorrect numbering of follow-up pages. Better strategies are:

- If you want no page numbers up to a certain point in the document and to start with page number 1 at this point, use `\pagenumbering{gobble}` immediately after `\begin{document}` and `\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}` at the point where numbering should start.
- If you want no page numbers on certain pages although these pages should feature "internal"  numbers (e.g. page 5 with text, then a page without displayed number, then page 7 with text), you should either issue `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the particular pages or (if those pages are empty save for headers/footers) load the [`emptypage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/emptypage) package. (For pages where new chapters start, many document classes provide automatic ways to change the page style to `empty`.)

Comment: My document is two sided with bindingoffset setted so I would that pages have correctly position.

Comment: `\pagenumbering` does not fiddle with the positioning of page numbers.